# Integration issue on Hibernate, websphere and DB2 database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2, websphere

**Issue Overview**

I'm facing an StaleConnectionException, whenever i deploy my Web application on the IBM Websphere v7.0.0.17. I'm using the datasource connection provided by Websphere through a JNDI Lookup.

```
ERROR 10 Apr 2014 01:41:20,101 server.startup : 2 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator - could not get database metadata
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: SEQNAME IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.51.90
```

**Problem Description**

Our Webapplication has developed based on `GWT`+`Spring`+`Hibernate` framework and it running on an `IBM Websphere v7` and it interacts with `IBM DB2` database. We consumes the datasource object(`JNDI` Lookup) configured on the `Websphere` App server.

From the error logs(attached), we understood that the issue occurs during Database Schema Validation against the `DB2` database. But, we have cross checked the `Hibernate` Configuration and Table Structure(schema) has no issues and it is working fine with a `tomcat` server. This below error appears only on `Websphere` while deploying the application.

I also followed some suggestion provided on technical forums by reducing the “`minimum_connection_size`” for the “`StaleConnectionException`”on the `Websphere’s` `datasource` properties, but it doesn’t help me to resolve this error.

**Error Snippet:**

```
2014-04-11 08:10:47,841                 ERROR  [SchemaValidator] could not get database metadata 
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: SEQNAME IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.51.90
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil.handleStaleStatement(WSJdbcUtil.java:849)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.mapException(AdapterUtil.java:2125)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil.mapException(WSJdbcUtil.java:1034)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcStatement.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.initSequences(DatabaseMetadata.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1707)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:380)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:731)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:616)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:610)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:726)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1268)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4678)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4766)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1273)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2045)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:441)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:655)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:617)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1332)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:595)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

**Environment Details:**

- Spring    - 3.0.5
- Hibernate - 3.5.6
- Database  - IBM DB2 v10

  **Spring JNDI Configuration:**

**NOTE:** No issues in Hibernate Configuration and Database Schema, both looks good.

Comment: Just a wild guess: did you add the hibernate sequence for pk auto increment? http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-206_sqlstate_42703.html

Comment: @Hannes: I'm using "identity", which would increment the pk  automatically and it doesn't need Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The DB2 error in this case most likely hints at a syntax error in the query. Make sure that the version of the JDBC driver on the application server matches the version of the DB2 server.

Comment: Yes, I have cross checked the JDBC Driver version which is supportable to DB2 server.

Comment: If you say so... Evidently, either the driver or the Hibernate framework issues an SQL statement that is not understood by the server. Since there's no DB2 v10 for Linux, Unix and Windows, I'm assuming you are using DB2 10 for z/OS, while your software seems to believe it is DB2 for LUW. The structure of the SYSIBM.SYSSEQUENCES table is different on these platforms.